How to make map which returns functions with different definitions
I' making react native app with expo, react-navigation and typescript.
I want to make flow manager (to separate screen views and screen switching logic) and for that I've made something like this:
private handleLogin = (nav: Navigation, action: "withGmail" | "withMail") => {
    ...
};

private handleBan = (nav: Navigation) => {
    ...
}

public navigationMap: { [k in StackScreens]: Function } = {
    Login: this.handleLogin,
    Ban: this.handleBan,
    Note: () => {},
    ...
}

That is convenient because in all components I can just do const onNavigate = flowManager.navigationMap[props.route.name];
Problem I want to solve is that onNavigate() doesn't have intellisense because my navigationMap has value set to Function.
How can I make intellisense bully me into passing nav: Navigation, action: "withGmail" | "withMail" when onNavigate is handleLogin or to make me pass just nav: Navigation when onNavigate is handleBan?
Ideally to make it implied from functions that are passed to navigationMap's keys?
I've tried several different function definitions, with generics also, but couldn't really figure it out.

Removed image and replaced it with shorter and more concise text.

To make TypeScript provide the intellisense for that with your current structure, TypeScript would have to be able to tell which function specifically (handleLogin or handleBan), you were trying to call when writing onNavigate(, which would defeat the purpose of having onNavigate since it would mean something like a big switch statement to narrow the type of props.route.name to the string literal type "Login" or "Ban", at which point you may as well call handleLogin or handleBan directly anyway. Dispatch maps/objects like the one you have work great when the parameters...

...are consistent across functions, but poorly when they aren't. If you can group your functions into categories, where all of the functions in each category have the same set of parameters, you could at least only have a branch per category rather than per function, but looking at the above it seems like that might be overkill or infeasible (no other function is going to have that same action parameter as handleLogin, I assume). Sadly I suspect you're best off just calling the handlers directly (in a big switch or similar), but hopefully someone else can come up with a better solution.

So if I do public navigationMap = { Login: this.handleLogin, ...}
everything works fine, but I want ts to make me have all keys from StackScreens and then it doesn't work. I think that's due to value signature in navigationMap's type?
